# Retrofit 2 - response body returns null (response code is 200)

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

I have a json file like this:

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "ApplicationList":[  
         {  
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"SomeApp"
         }
      ],
      "Token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIyMyIsIm5iZiI6MTUxNDIwMDkyMiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ1NzM2OTIyLCJpYXQiOjE1MTQyMDA5MjJ9.9nyaBfbxPlg8T8WkbBBi34II9NZMtyRpeEJ1s1XCJlo"
   },
   "errorMessageId":0,
   "errorMessage":null
}
```

I'm using Retrofit library and I have checked the response with Interceptor level BODY which shows that response is good (like above).

I have created models using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  but for some reason, parsing to java model isn't going as supposed to.  I'm getting all null values for attributes in model.

Here are my model classes:

```
public class SignInUsersResponse implements Parcelable{

public Response response;
public Integer errorMessageId;
public String errorMessage;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SignInUsersResponse{" +
            "response=" + response +
            ", errorMessageId=" + errorMessageId +
            ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(this.response, flags);
    dest.writeValue(this.errorMessageId);
    dest.writeString(this.errorMessage);
}

public SignInUsersResponse() {
}

protected SignInUsersResponse(Parcel in) {
    this.response = in.readParcelable(Response.class.getClassLoader());
    this.errorMessageId = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    this.errorMessage = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<SignInUsersResponse> CREATOR = new Creator<SignInUsersResponse>() {
    @Override
    public SignInUsersResponse createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new SignInUsersResponse(source);
    }

    @Override
    public SignInUsersResponse[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SignInUsersResponse[size];
    }
};
}


public class Response implements Parcelable{

public List<ApplicationList> applicationList = null;
public String token;


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Response{" +
            "applicationList=" + applicationList +
            ", token='" + token + '\'' +
            '}';
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeTypedList(this.applicationList);
    dest.writeString(this.token);
}

public Response() {
}

protected Response(Parcel in) {
    this.applicationList = in.createTypedArrayList(ApplicationList.CREATOR);
    this.token = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Response> CREATOR = new Creator<Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Response(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Response[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Response[size];
    }
};
}


public class ApplicationList implements Parcelable{

public Integer id;
public String name;



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ApplicationList{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
}

public ApplicationList() {
}

protected ApplicationList(Parcel in) {
    this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    this.name = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ApplicationList> CREATOR = new Creator<ApplicationList>() {
    @Override
    public ApplicationList createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ApplicationList(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ApplicationList[size];
    }
};
}
```

All three are in different class files.

And this is how I call the server:

```
 RHDRService rhdrService = ApiUtilsUser.rhdrService(Constants.RHUSER_BASE_URL);
    Call<SignInUsersResponse> call = rhdrService.signInUser(signInUserPost);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInUsersResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SignInUsersResponse> call, Response<SignInUsersResponse> response) {
            Log.d("test", response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SignInUsersResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

This is what is logged:

> D/test: SignInUsersResponse{response=Response{applicationList=null, token='null'}, errorMessageId=0, errorMessage='null'}

This is how the other files which are used for Retrofit call are declared:

```
public class ApiUtilsUser {

    public static RHDRService rhdrService(String base_url) {
        return RetroFitClientUser.getClient(base_url).create(RHDRService.class);
    }
}


public class RetroFitClientUser {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        // add your other interceptors …
        // add logging as last interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())             // Ako nećemo logovanje onda ova linija ne treba
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}




public interface RHDRService {

    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
    @POST("api/user/signin")
    Call<SignInUsersResponse> signInUser (@Body SignInUserPost signInUserPost);
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you create your API service, `OkHttpClient` and `Gson `.

Comment: I've added the Retrofit declaration and the call.  Until now I never had any problem using this schema. I think that there is a problem with my models according to the json file which I receive in response.

Comment: You are right, the issue seems to be in your model. I wanted to make sure that you actually added a `GsonConverterFactory`.
Add `@SerializedName("ApplicationList")` to your model before `List<ApplicationList> applicationList`.

Comment: Ok.  It wasn't enough, but you helped me to get back on right track.  I actually added **SerializedName**  and **Expose**  to every attribute in all 3 classes, and then it worked!
Can you explain me why was it necessary?  Until now implementing parcalable was enough to work with responses and classes.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not providing an explanation! The issue is is that in your JSON `ApplicationList` is capitalised. By default, Gson uses `FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY` which is case sensitive. By adding `@SerializedName` to your model, you are telling Gson to which field to map the `ApplicationList` value. It has nothing to do with parcalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON and POJO differ.

By default, Gson uses [`FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY` as field naming policy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html). This field naming policy is used to map the JSON to your POJO and it is case sensitive.

You can either use a different field naming policy or use `@SerializedName` to indicate that the field should be deserialized with the given name.

```
class MyPojo {
     @SerializedName("ApplicationList")
     List<Application> applicationList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I missed the capitalized names :(